# Returning a value based on matching one lists values to another list based on order

Tags: python, list

I have four lists:

```
user = [0,0,1,1]
names = ["jake","ryan","paul","david"]
disliked_index = [0,1]
ranked_names = ["paul","ryan","david","jake"]
```

List "user" holds a user's response to which names they like (1 if like, 0 if dislike) from list "names". disliked_index holds the list spots that user indicated 0 in the user list. ranked_names holds the names ranked from most popular to least popular based on the data set (multiple students). What I am trying to achieve is to return the most popular name that the user responded they didn't like. So that

```
mostpopular_unlikedname = "ryan"
```

So far what I have done is:

```
placement = []
for i in disliked_index:
    a = names[i]
    placement.append(a)
```

Where I now have a list that holds the names the user did not like.

```
placement = ["jake","ryan"]
```

Here my logic is to run a loop to check which names in the placement list appear in the ranked_names list and get added to the top_name list in the order from most popular to least.

```
top_name =[]
for i in range(len(ranked_names)):
    if ranked_names[i] == placement:
        top_name.append[i]
```

Nothing ends up being added to the top_name list. I am stuck on this part and wanted to see if this is an alright direction to continue or if I should try something else.
Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need `disliked_index` list for this. Just do something along these lines:

```
dis_pos = []
for name, sentiment in zip(names,user):
    if sentiment == 0:
        dis_pos.append(ranked_names.index(name))
mostpopular_unlikedname = ranked_names[min(dis_pos)]
print(mostpopular_unlikedname)
```

Output:

```
ryan
```

Comment: thank you so much! that helped a lot, I ended up just changing the 0 to a 1 and it worked perfectly. Appreciate it a lot!!